# How to run the html and jquery code in django?

Tags: python, jquery, html, django

I run the jquery file in html and it works but whenever I run the code within django framework within {%block content%} {%endblock%} the sliding function does not work. Why and how to resolve this issue?

```
{% extends 'testapp/base.html' %}
{%block content%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
     });
   });
 </script>
<style>
    #panel {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
    </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
  </body>
</html>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: is there anyone answer my question?

Comment: Please post 'base.html' codes

Comment: It's a navigation bar and the coding is so much.

Comment: You extend 'base.html' and again use '<html>' tag .

Comment: Do you mean that I should put all my code of index.html into base.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `html`,`head`, `body` tags to `base.html`:

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
   <head>
    <script 
       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <style>
    #panel {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body> 
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.html:**

```
{% extends 'testapp/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip").click(function(){
          $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to answer? I have tried this code but it's not working.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded?

Comment: whenever I remove {%block content%} {%endblock%} it works but whenever I put it didn't.